# Installing Tomcat for my Mac Local Environment

Tags: macos, tomcat

I need to install Tomcat on my local mac environment. Only tutorials I am finding are from some time ago. Running Snow Leopard. Anyone know of any good resources for this?

Comment: apache is loaded already, is that good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Macports](http://www.macports.org/) is your friend in this case. If you need to get Tomcat up and running quickly and don't want to worry about install details, you can install it with macports using `port install tomcat5` (or tomcat6). There should be output from port near the end of the install that tells you how to set Tomcat to start up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go with Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition (http://www.gopivotal.com/products/pivotal-tc-server), which is a free drop-in replacement for Apache Tomcat.

Installing it on OSX straightforward. First, open Terminal then install HomeBrew if you don't have it:

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Next, run the following Homebrew command:

brew tap pivotal/tap && brew install tcserver

This will connect to the Pivotal HomeBrew repository, then download and install tc Server. From there you can follow the instructions in the Terminal.

Full disclosure: I work for Pivotal and am part of the tc Server product team, and one of our goals is to make it super easy to get started with tc Server on OSX. Any questions, you can reach me at @alsargent on Twitter.